# S3 Bucket copy object

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I'm currently working on the AWS s3 bucket and its services. I'm copying my object from one bucket to another bucket within the folder. And in response, I'm comparing for eTags from metadata. If these tags are equal then I'm returning destination bucket's image path. But While from reactjs I'm rendering my response, it is showing me a broken image. and on refresh, it is showing me the proper results. I'm not getting why this is happening.

```
 ObjectMetadata metadata = s3client.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, sourceKey);
            CopyObjectResult copyObjectResult = s3client.copyObject(bucketName, sourceKey, bucketName, destinationKey);
            if (metadata.getETag().equals(copyObjectResult.getETag())) {
                s3client.deleteObject(bucketName, sourceKey);

                LOG.info("profile successfully uploaded to bucket");
                return s3BucketConfiguration.getS3URL() + "/" + Constants.REVIEWER_DIR + "/" + FilenameUtils.getName(url.getPath());
            } else {
                LOG.error("error in upload profile to bucket");
                return String.format("%s/%s/%s", s3BucketConfiguration.getS3URL(), Constants.REVIEWER_DIR, Constants.DEFAULT_IMAGE);
            }
```

Here each time I got LOG : profile successfully uploaded to bucket.
And still, it renders broken image. I'm confused that what should be the problem is.
please help me out with this.

Comment: Did you tried to check objects in s3 buckets from AWS Console? And they metadata?

Comment: Is it really required?? I guess it is a redundant call to AWS service because I'm already getting the response in copyObjectResult object.